# How can I validate if a record can be added at the SQL level using Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

If I want to make some checks before inserting a row into the database, I know that I can run the following code:

```
public bool BookSeat(int userId, string seatNumber)
{
    If (IsSeatStillAvailable(seatNumber))
    {
        var ticket = new Ticket(userId, seatNumber);
        _dbContext.Tickets(ticket);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private bool IsSeatStillAvailable(seatNumber)
{
    var seatTaken = _dbcontext.Tickets.Any(w => w.seatNumber == seatNumber);
    return !seatTaken;
}
```

This will do a call to the database to see if the seat is taken and then do a second call to book the seat. **BUT** in that time it might have already been booked.

I know in simple examples, I can create an index, but my use case is much more complex.

Is there a way that I can generate the SQL statement on the insert so that it can produce an ATOMIC transaction?

To produce something like (excuse the clumsy SQL):

```
IF (SELECT TOP 1 Count(*) FROM Tickets = 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Tickets (UserId, SeatNumber) 
    VALUES (@UserId, @SeatNumber);

    RETURN true
END;

RETURN false
```

Comment: With EF you should use unique indexes to prevent duplicates and then catch any errors.

Comment: Please see my reply to @Cromm

Comment: I don't think it's possible in EF Core.

Comment: If you don't want to use a unique index and catch errors, then you'll have to use SQL Queries with transactions.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries  And so the solution will depend on which platform you are using.  But in SQL Server you would need a transaction and  `(UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)` table hints on the query that checks whether the row exists.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is concurrency handling and optimistic locking :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: Although that's a good call when doing an update what about the insert. On the example I dont want to do an insert if a record already exists. 
I'm thinking that I might need to run it as a transaction - Do the select and if ok then to the insert. My worry then is locking the database too long. My scenario includes queues and microservices so they could be lots of requests very close together.